# how to multiply two tensor on an axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

let say I got two tensor where tensor A has shape (100,7), tensor B has shape (100,7,64).
I want to pick the first item from A and B and multiply them by tf.matmul that result in shape (1,64) and then the next item as so on.then finally combine all tensor and get a tensor with shape (100,64).I can't find any function to do this...
any helps?

edit:
i can do this with the code below but very slow any tensorflow function for this?

```
outputs = []
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    outputs = outputs + [tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(A[i],0),B[i])[0]]
outputs = tf.stack(outputs,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because I like squeezes nothing else

**[ Sample ]:**

```
Matrix_A = tf.linspace(tf.zeros([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.math.multiply(tf.ones([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.constant([10.0], tf.float32)), 1, axis=2)                         
Matrix_B = tf.linspace(tf.zeros([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.math.multiply(tf.ones([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.constant([10.0], tf.float32)), 64, axis=2)
Matrix_A = tf.linspace(tf.zeros([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.math.multiply(tf.ones([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.constant([10.0], tf.float32)), 1, axis=2)
Matrix_B = tf.linspace(tf.zeros([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.math.multiply(tf.ones([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.constant([10.0], tf.float32)), 64, axis=2)
tf.slice(Matrix_A, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 1]).shape) + " and " + str(tf.slice(Matrix_B, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 64])
tf.math.multiply( tf.slice(Matrix_A, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 1]), tf.slice(Matrix_B, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 64]) )
tf.squeeze(tf.slice(tf.math.multiply( tf.slice(Matrix_A, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 1]), tf.slice(Matrix_B, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 64]) ), [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 64])))
```

**[ Output ]:**

```
 * Slice or slice windows


1. Create constants Matrix A and Matrix B with shape: (100, 7, 1) and (100, 7, 64)
   Matrix_A = tf.linspace(tf.zeros([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.math.multiply(tf.ones([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.constant([10.0], tf.float32)), 1, axis=2)
   Matrix_B = tf.linspace(tf.zeros([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.math.multiply(tf.ones([100, 7], tf.float32), tf.constant([10.0], tf.float32)), 64, axis=2)

 ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
2. Slice Matrix A and Matrix B target shape: (100, 1, 1) and (100, 1, 64)
   tf.slice(Matrix_A, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 1])
   tf.slice(Matrix_B, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 64])

 ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
3. Multiply them into target shape: (100, 1, 64)
   tf.math.multiply( tf.slice(Matrix_A, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 1]), tf.slice(Matrix_B, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 64]) )

 ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
4. Squeeze dimension: tf.Tensor([100  64], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
   tf.squeeze(tf.slice(tf.math.multiply( tf.slice(Matrix_A, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 1]), tf.slice(Matrix_B, [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 64]) ), [0, 0, 0], [100, 1, 64])))

 ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: oh thank you I didn't expect anyone will help. but this isn't the way I want. I had provide code for exactly what I want but I used loop in the process. I suspect using loop is the bottleneck for speed so i want to know if there is any function for it. sorry for the unclear in my question.

Comment: It is easy as in the example by multiplying each element you can use TF.math.multiply. It is exactly similar dimension output you question.

Comment: I didn't know tf.multiply has such behaviour,my code is a lot faster now thank you x1000